# Route Mapping not working with "area"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I've been reading a lot about this problem, and I can't figure this out.

Everything is pretty straightforward with routing and ASP .NET MVC, but I'm stuck with this.

The problem is that I'm trying to make a GET to a given url with this form:

{area}/{controller}/{action}

But the {area} is not being registered. My default route is not working either (not working in the sense that I need to go to localhost:port/Home instead of just going to localhost:port/

This is my code:

RouteConfig:

```
public class RouteConfig
{
   public static void RegisterRoute(RouteCollection routes)
   {
      routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}")

      route.MapRoute(
         "Default",
         "{controller}/{action}",
         new {controller = "Home", action = "Index"}
      );
   }

}
```

This is the Area that is not being registered:

```
public class TransaccionesAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration
{
    public override string AreaName
    {
        get{
            return “Transacciones”; 
        }
    }

    public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context){
        context.MapRoute(
            "Transacciones_default",
            "Transacciones/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { controller = "Transacciones", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Option}
            );
        }
    }
```

Finally, this is my global.asax (I do call AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas() method):

```
protected void Application_Start(){

   AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
   FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
   RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
   BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

}
```

I will really appreciate some advice with this, I think I have spent enough time googling :O)

Comment: By "not working" you mean that you get `404 not found`?

Comment: yes, Sir. Let me update to make it clear. Thanks @haim770

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20779264/mvc-routing-not-working) questions was the one that helped me.

The thing is, the order in the routes' registration is very important. Considering that, I started checking my other areas registration, and I found out that all the requests where falling into the first rule that was a general rule like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name : "Default",
    url  : {controller}{action}{id}
);
```

So, after that rule, none of the rules were being considered.

Thanks everyone for trying to help, bests!

Answer (score 2):

Just try this

RouteConfig:

```
public class RouteConfig
{
   public static void RegisterRoute(RouteCollection routes)
   {
     routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}")

     route.MapRoute(
     name: "Default",
     url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
     defaults: new {controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
      );
   }
}
```

This is the Area that is not being registered:

```
  public class TransaccionesAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration
  {
    public override string AreaName
    {
      get{
          return “Transacciones”; 
      }
    }

  public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context){
    context.MapRoute(
        “Transacciones_default”,
        “Transacciones/{controller}/{action}/{id}”,
        new { action = ”Index”, id = UrlParameter.Optional },
        new string[] { "MyApp.Transacciones.Controllers" }  // specify the new namespace
       );
    }
}


    ------------------------------OR Try This--------------------------------

 public class RouteConfig
 {
   public static void RegisterRoute(RouteCollection routes)
   {
     routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}")
     AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

     route.MapRoute(
     name: "Default",
     url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
     defaults: new {controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
      );
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer, but this is still not working. I have tried both of them

Answer (score 2):

**Reason why default route is not working**

Because you never registered a default one. Add this line in the `RouteConfig` -

```
routes.MapRoute("Home", "", new { Controller = "Home", Action = "Index" });
```

So the final code should look like this -

```
public class RouteConfig
{
   public static void RegisterRoute(RouteCollection routes)
   {
      routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}")

      routes.MapRoute("Home", "", new { Controller = "Home", Action = "Index" });

      route.MapRoute(
         "Default",
         "{controller}/{action}",
         new {controller = "Home", action = "Index"}
      );
   }
}
```

**Possible reason why Area seems not working**

May be the same reason also the Area registration seems not working. Try adding the following line in area registration -

```
routes.MapRoute("Transacciones_Home", "Transacciones", new { Controller = "Transacciones", Action = "Index" });
```

So it looks like -

```
public class TransaccionesAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration
{
    public override string AreaName
    {
        get{
            return “Transacciones”; 
        }
    }

    public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context){
        routes.MapRoute("Transacciones_Home", "Transacciones", new { Controller = "Transacciones", Action = "Index" });

        context.MapRoute(
            “Transacciones_default”,
            “Transacciones/{controller}/{action}/{id}”,
            new { controller = “Transacciones”, action = ”Index”, id = UrlParameter.Option}
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: is not working. I suppose you meant 'context...' instead of 'routes...' in the 'TransaccionesAreaRegistration' class.